# Fitch style proof of $(\neg B \to \neg A) \leftrightarrow (A \to B)$

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, natural-deduction, formal-proofs

I have been stuck on this proof for a while. Here's where I'm at:

Goal $(\neg B \to \neg A) \leftrightarrow (A \to B)$

l 1. $A \to B$

ll 2. $\neg B$

lll 3. $A$

lll 4. $B$              Elim 1,3

lll 5. $\neg B$             Reit

ll 6. $A \to \neg B$         Into 3-5

ll 7. $\neg A$              ????

l $\neg B \to \neg A$            Into 2-7

If someone can help it will be great. Thank you

Comment: This is the second question in propositional calculus which you tagged as first order logic. Please be aware of the difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't get where you're going from step 6, but note the following.

In 4. you got $B$ and in the same subproof you got $\neg B$. You can infer a contradiction and proceed with $\neg$-$\text{Intro}$.

The other subproof should be similar.

**Edit:** See what I mean below.

[image]

Comment: I am sorry but I am not quite sure what u mean. Can u please explain? Thank you

Comment: @user3727903 Don't apologize. See the edit.

Comment: lol that was so helpful. thank you but any suggestions on connecting both sentences or that's how I would end the proof? I am still new at this. thanks again

Comment: @user3727903 From where I left off you should start a new subproof with premise $\neg B\to \neg A$ and infer $A\to B$. When you have both subproofs, you can use $\leftrightarrow$-$\text{Intro}$ on them to conclude.

Comment: @user3727903 In case it wasn't clear, the new subproof I mention should be at the same level as the one I did, not inside it.

Comment: Thank You very much for your help. I was able to correctly answer the proof. Would it be possible to e-mail you about other proofs that I am having trouble with?

Comment: @user3727903 I don't want to give you my e-mail. Not only that, everybody wins if you post your questions here on MSE. If I see them, if I have the time and no helps by the time I can answer, I will help you. Between me, [Mauro](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/108274/mauro-allegranza) and [Doug](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/11300/doug-spoonwood), it is unlikely that you'll not get an answer in this sort of thing.

Answer (score 0):

Premises:

1. A ∨ B
2. C → ¬B
3. ¬C → ¬A
4. ¬B

Logical consequence: (A ↔ C)??