# formal proof of $(p → q) → (¬q → ¬p)$

Tags: natural-deduction

I'm asked to give a formal proof of $(p → q) → (¬q → ¬p)$ using natural deduction. Is that like saying prove $⊢ (p → q) → (¬q → ¬p$), where it should be proved from nothing?

Comment: Exactly; you have to start assuming one or more premises that you will discharge later.

Comment: Please use MathJax in future.

Comment: Assume $q$ follows from $p$. Further assume not $q$. What can you say about $p$? By the way, this is called the contrapositive.

Comment: [Not a duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/829860/fitch-style-proof-of-neg-b-to-neg-a-leftrightarrow-a-to-b), but the only answer to this question solves 95% of this problem.

Comment: What rules do you have to work with?  There are many different systems of 'natural deduction', each with their own set of rules.

Answer (score 1):

The following proof uses modus tollens (MT):

[image]

However, one can derive the modus tollens rule in the following way. This uses the proof provided on page 138 of *forallx* linked to below along with a link to the proof checker used here:

[image]

---

Kevin Klement's JavaScript/PHP Fitch-style natural deduction proof editor and checker http://proofs.openlogicproject.org/

P. D. Magnus, Tim Button with additions by J. Robert Loftis remixed and revised by Aaron Thomas-Bolduc, Richard Zach, forallx Calgary Remix: An Introduction to Formal Logic, Winter 2018. http://forallx.openlogicproject.org/

Answer (score 0):

Hint: the following statements are all equivalent:

- $p\to q$
- $\neg p\lor q$
- $\neg\neg q\lor\neg p$
- $\neg q\to\neg p$

Comment: The formal proof that comes naturally to me uses none of this. How is this helpful?

Comment: @GitGud If you have a different route, well done. But to any future reader considering this problem who doesn't, the use comes in providing a sequence of statements worth proving equivalent. How you stitch them together into a proof depends on your preferred notation.

Comment: I didn't say what I should have said. How do you go from this to a formal proof? As I see it, you need to go to the moon and back, I don't see how this can be helpful.